# Magento Stylesheet is not loading after clearing cache

Tags: magento, stylesheet

I am modifying a Magento theme. After clearing cache, the stylesheet on homepage is not loading anymore. I can see the stylesheet path is already there but when i clicked on it it says not found. Any ideas ... why it is happening. Please help.

But on category page, the stylesheet is loading properly.

Strange thing is that the homepage http://www.knocknok-fashion.com/index.php is loading the stylesheet perfectly, but http://www.knocknok-fashion.com/ without the “index.php” is not loading the stylesheet.

Comment: go to system >> developer >> Css Merge set No and check

Comment: Under system i cannot locate any "developer" link.

Comment: System >> Configuration Menu At last Advanced >> Developr

Comment: I have set "Css Merge" to "No" but nothing change. Here is my url: http://www.knocknok-fashion.com/

Comment: on category page "Css Merge = No" is working, but it seems nothing affects the homepage. On homepage there is still showing the long "6fce160edc8335ff0b1327f3c55efa93.css" css path.

Comment: disable cache and check

Comment: Disable the cache. But nothing change.

Comment: some other pages are also showing the same css as the homepage. ( which is non existed ) Can it be coming from a different theme? By the way is it possible to write css only for the homepage in a static file? I cannot understand where the css is coming from for the homepage.

Comment: htaccess file are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been resolved! I have cleared the Magento cache by clicking "Purge Varnish" under "Mgt Varnish Cache Management" and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, View the source of your page and click the css links, if it is pointed correctly it should bring you to the css page.

Please check whether you have changed Home page design from Admin Panel.

I mean go to Cms >> Pages

Open Home Page.

Click on Design tab.

Check value of "Custom Theme" under "Custom Design".

If still you find any trouble, then please provide your website's URL.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. Css is not loading when i viewing the source code. here is my url: http://www.knocknok-fashion.com/

Comment: On my end, Home page is loading correctly. I mean css is loading for Home Page in both cases, i.e. with index.php and without index.php.